# How to make squeue display time limits in hours only?

Tags: format, slurm

When viewing submitted jobs managed by Slurm, I would like to have the time limit column (specified by %l) to show only hours, instead of the usual days-hours:minutes:seconds format. This is the command I am currently using:

```
squeue --format="%.6i %.5P %.25j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.5l %.15b %.5C %.6D %R" --sort=+i --me
```

and this is the example output:

> 276350  qgpu     jobname  username  RUNNING    1:14:14 1-00:00:00 gres:gpu:v100:1    18      1 s31n02

So, in this case, I would like the elapsed time to remain as is (1:14:14), but the time limit to change from 1-00:00:00 to 24. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way Slurm displays the dates. Elapsed time will eventually be displayed the same way (`days-hours:minutes:seconds`) after `23:59:59`.

You can use a wrapper script to convert into a different format. Or if you know the time limit is no more than a day, just set the time limit to 23:59:00 by using `--time=1439`.

```
salloc -N1 --time=1439 bash
```

Using your `squeue` command:

> 166 mypartition               interactive    jyvet  RUNNING       7:36 23:59:00             N/A     1      1 mynode